# SSRS not available in SharePoint server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

I have 2 SQL Servers (SQL01 has all Content DBs and SQL02 has all Service App DBs) and 2 SharePoint 2013 Servers with Enterprise edition. Just couple days ago, I installed Power Pivot in SP mode and Analysis Services on SQL Server(SQL02). I successfully configured the Power Pivot, but I don't see SSRS Services Application listed under Manage Service Application to create one.When I try to run "Install-SPRSService" on SP Servers, I get 'The term Install-SPRSService is not recognized error. What am I missing here? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couples of things to make sure:

1. install SQL Server Reporting Services in SharePoint mode
2. the SQL Server Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint 2013. I think this part is missing that's why your command is not recognized.

Check more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144289.aspx#bkmk_no_ssrs_service

Comment: I have installed both. Also I have Reporting Services- Native and Analysis Services on all same instance. Is that right? And do I need to install these on both the SQL Server. Right now, I have it on only one server(SQL02).

Comment: I uninstalled Reporting Services native mode and reinstalled "Reporting Services - SharePoint" and "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" on both SQL servers. But I am still getting the same error. The term 'Install-SPRSService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,.... I am working on this issue for sometime now, but couldn't find a solution. Any help?? Thanks

Comment: Is sharepoint server are different than sql server or everything on one box?

Comment: Did u install anything related to ssrs on sharepoint server?

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment and I deleted it. I installed "Reporting Services - SharePoint" and "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" on SharePoint servers and installed everything on SQL Servers. And now I could create SQL Servers Reporting Services on SharePoint.